# Seleção de tabelas SQL

Tags: php

E ae Pessoal, blz? Gente, estou com um probleminha, tenho 3 Tabelas SQL, uma chamada alunos, outra chamada colaborador e outra de postagens

Na tabela **alunos** temos:

```
id
nome;
img;
email;
pass;
end;
status
matricula
dash
...
```

Na tabela **colaborado**r temos:

```
id
nome
img
email
pass
end
status
codigo
```

E na tabela **postagem** temos:

```
id
id_user (id do usuário q postou a publicação)
publicacao
img
date
```

Meu problema é o seguinte, eu tenho uma conexão a tabela **postagem**:

```
<?php
    $sqlPublic = "SELECT * FROM postagem ORDER BY id DESC";
    $resultPublic = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlPublic);
?>
```

E tenho um `While` para apresentar todas as publicações dessa forma:

```
<?php while ($public = mysqli_fetch_array($resultPublic)) { ?>
    <div class="publicacao">
        div class="headerPost">
    <?php
        $id_Post = $public['id']; //A partir daqui pega os dados da publicação do $public que está sendo feita no while com array;
        $id_user = $public['id_user'];
        $postagem = $public['postagem'];
        $datePost = $public['datePost'];
        $sqlPostUser = "SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE id = '$id_user'"; // Aqui eu faço a conexão com a tabela alunos com sql_assoc para associar cada publicação com o usuário que à postou com referência no ID do usuário, com o id cadastrado na publicação.
        $queryPostUser = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlPostUser);
        $linhaAssoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryPostUser);
        $dasheres = $linhaAssoc['dash'];
    ?>
    <div class="arPer">
        <div class="perfilPost">
            <div class="perfilFoto">
                <img src="../arquivs/perfil/<?php echo $linhaAssoc['img']; ?>" />
            </div>
            <a href=""><h1><?php
                $linhaNameAssoc = $linhaAssoc['name_user'];
                $linhaNameAssoc = explode(" ", $linhaNameAssoc);
                echo $linhaNameAssoc[0]." ".$linhaNameAssoc[1];
            ?></h1></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
O restante do código é apenas a estrutura normal...
```

Prosseguindo... O problema é o seguinte, eu consigo listar com `while` todas as publicações, até aí beleza, só que, como podem ver só tem referência com a tabela **alunos**, e preciso também fazer com a tabela **colaborador**, por que se um colaborador fizer a postagem na forma que está, não vai aparecer os dados dele, e vai dar erro na exibição, eu tentei fazer de várias formas a seleção das duas tabelas (**alunos** & **colaborador**), mas não consegui, tentei usando `UNION` mas não consegui, tentei com `JOIN`, mas para esse caso ele não serve, eu tive quase o mesmo problema com a listagem de usuários, mas eu consegui resolver, esse é ainda um pouco mais complicado, por favor, quem puder me ajudar responde aí, queria fazer a seleção das duas tabelas pra poder exibir corretamente as publicações... Vou tentar algo que me venho a mente agora, mas só testar mesmo

ME DESCULPEM PELO TAMANHO DISSO, era pra ficar bem claro o que tá acontecendo.

Answer (score 2):

(desculpa meu português não sou nativo)

Na verdade é normal fazer esse tipo de coisa kkk, mas você pode fazer o mesmo com uma consulta singular:

```
$sqlPublic = SELECT * FROM postagem AS posta LEFT OUTER JOIN alunos AS alu ON alu.id = posta.id_user LEFT OUTER JOIN colaborador AS cola.id ON cola.id = posta.id_user ORDER BY posta.id DESC;

$resultPublic = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlPublic);
```

Para você poder selecionar algum campo, você usa o prefixo da tabela com o nome do campo. Por exemplo: `__$public['alu.nome']__` é o nome do aluno e `__$public['cola.nome']__` é o nome do colaborador.

Logo, quando você faz o `while`, o problema vai ser que se a postagem foi feita com um colaborador, então os dados de aluno serão `NULL` e vice-versa. Então você primeiro tem que selecionar o qual campo do qual tabela vai usar, mas isso pode ser resolver usando o operador ternário do seguinte jeito para alocar o nome de usuário:

```
$nome_user = (!is_null($public['alu.nome'])) ? $public['alu.nome'] : $public['cola.nome'];
```

Suponho, que uma postagem tem como criador um colaborador ou um aluno, então, se um é `NULL` você toma o valor do outro. E assim você pode ir fazendo com outros campos de colaborador e aluno.

Espero que possa entender o que falei.

Comment: kkkkkkkk Vllw pelo apoio da gambiarra kkkkk

Aah, e sua ideia me ajudou, ainda vou testá-la, mas me ajudou pq me esclareceu mais sobre as formas de se usar o JOIN, pois eu tinha muita dúvida em relação a isso, obg mesmo valeu

Answer (score 0):

consegui fazer uma super gambiarra kkkkkkk

Não é nada profissional isso. Mas foi o que deu... Futuramente pretendo melhorar isso com certeza.

Na parte da seleção da tabela **alunos** para dar um assoc, eu fiz o seguinte, eu fiz duas query diferentes, uma para cada tabela, como mostra a seguir:

```
<?php
$id_Post = $public['id'];
    $id_user = $public['id_user'];
    $postagem = $public['postagem'];
    $datePost = $public['datePost'];
    $assocIf = "SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE id = '$id_user'";
    $associf = "SELECT * FROM colaborador WHERE id = '$id_user'";
    $queryAss = mysqli_query($conn, $assocIf);
    $queryass = mysqli_query($conn, $associf);
    $alunos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryAss);
    $colaborador = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryass);
?>
```

E a "GAMBIARRA" que eu fiz foi a seguinte, peguei e fiz apenas um if|else if, como mostrado a seguir:

```
if($alunos['id'] === $id_user){
    $sqlAlunos = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE id = '$id_user'");
    $linhaAssoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlAlunos);
}else if($colaborador['id'] === $id_user){
    $sqlAlunos = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM colaborador WHERE id = '$id_user'");
    $linhaAssoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlAlunos);
}
```

Deu certo, mas como eu disse, não acho isso mt profissional.